# Kubernetes creating service took too long

Tags: kubernetes

I have been trying to deploy my Kubernetes service, but it says still pending and keep pending. I waited 1 day and half but still pending.

[Kubernetes service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xItDM.png)

#### Static-Site-Service.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: static-site-service
  annotations:
    imageregistry: "https://hub.docker.com/"
  labels:
    app: static-site
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: static-site
  sessionAffinity: None
```

Comment: In kubernetes by default nothing assigns a load balancer IP address, because it's often a 3rd party thing. So, in your environment - what component assigns an LB IP to the services? If you have not installed and configured anything - it's expected to be always pending. Depending on your circumstances - there are few options if you _really need it_.

Comment: @zerkms how I can check it? I have configured a little bit with the `systemd` and nothing else. And on the `get nodes` it shows status `NotReady`

Comment: "how I can check it?" --- you don't need to _check_. If you have not configured it - you don't have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#external-load-balancer-providers):

> It is important to note that the datapath for this functionality is provided by a load balancer external to the Kubernetes cluster.
>
> When the Service type is set to LoadBalancer, Kubernetes provides functionality equivalent to type equals ClusterIP to pods within the cluster and extends it by programming the (external to Kubernetes) load balancer with entries for the Kubernetes pods. The Kubernetes service controller automates the creation of the external load balancer, health checks (if needed), firewall rules (if needed) and retrieves the external IP allocated by the cloud provider and populates it in the service object.

In other words your kubernetes cluster need to know how to set up a Load Balancer, because it's a feature provided by the environment where the cluster is running rather than by kubernetes itself.

For example, if you are running kubernetes on AWS and your `Controller Manager` is set up correctly, every time you create a `Service` with type `LoadBalancer` a new ELB will be created for you.

The same happens with all other supported cloud providers (Azure, GCE, Digital Ocean and others).

If you are running on-premise or on an unsupported cloud provider, nothing will create a `LoadBalancer` for you and the service will be `pending` forever as long as you don't set up a dedicated solution such as `MetalLB` just to name a random one.

I suggest reading [this blog post](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/load-balancing-on-prem/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

in K8S type 'Loadbalancer' in service generally we use in the cloud environment. according to the error i am assuming you are not using any cloud environment. so you can switch to other service types.

In case you still want to proceed and experiment then you can assign IP manually in same block of the type LoadBalancer. it will assign the IP and service will come out of the pending state.

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    spec:
      ...
      type: LoadBalancer
      loadBalancerIP: <your IP>
```